# INSERT DELAYED vs. Write-behind in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, caching, insert

What is the best way to avoid the overhead generated by executing many INSERT queries for logging purposes in a PHP/MySQL application? So far I have narrowed the solutions down to:

1. Using the **INSERT DELAYED** statement. I have a suspicion this will actually be slower, considering there will be many writes and few reads to queue and merge them behind.
2. Using a cache module supporting **write-behind**. However, it seems like there is no such module for PHP. This is also discussed here, though the answers are 3 years old and new technology has emerged since then: [How to implement background/asynchronous write-behind caching in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327035/how-to-implement-background-asynchronous-write-behind-caching-in-php)

Not losing log entries is important.

Comment: removing all indexes (except maybe an auto-increment PK) is a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `archive` engine for the log tables.
It's optimized for the workload of keeping a log.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/archive-storage-engine.html

Note that this engine does not support indexes which speeds up inserts, but slows down selects.